# Where is the mistake in my program? (sorting by age)

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort people by their age but somehow the months and the years are overwritten with the value from some other person. I already tried finding the mistake but wasn't successful.

```
void sortPersonsByAge(struct person *first, int cnt) {
    int i, j;
    struct person *oldest = first;

    for (j = 0; j < cnt-1; j++)
    {
        oldest = first + j;
        for (i = j; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            struct person *person = first + i;
            if (person->year_of_birth < oldest->year_of_birth)
                oldest = person; // es gibt einen neuen Altersrekord
            else if (person->year_of_birth = oldest->year_of_birth) 
            // in this else if is the mistake somewhere
            {
                if (person->month_of_birth < oldest->month_of_birth)
                    oldest = person;
                else if (person->month_of_birth = oldest->month_of_birth)
                    if (person->day_of_birth < oldest->day_of_birth)
                        oldest = person;
            }
        }
        // let's swap the first person with the oldest person

        struct person tmp; // Zwischenspeicher
        tmp = *(first+j);
        *(first+j) = *oldest;
        *oldest = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: it sorts the people after age and i have everything declared in the code but here is the problem

Comment: Did you see that you use assignement operator `=` instead of equality operator `==` 2 times ? `person->year_of_birth = oldest->year_of_birth` and `person->month_of_birth = oldest->month_of_birth`

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. A debugger is a crucial tool for any programmer, professional or hobbyist. Using a debugger you can step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Seeing a variable unexpectedly change will tell you a lot.

Comment: Rather, configure the compiler correctly so that it warns against assignment inside conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions in the statements

```
    else if (person->year_of_birth = oldest->year_of_birth)

    else if (person->month_of_birth = oldest->month_of_birth)
```

**are always true** (supposing `oldest->year_of_birth` and `oldest->month_of_birth` are not zero) as the value of **assignment** operator `=` is the value of its right-side.

You probably wanted operator of **comparison**, which is `==` (double `=`).

Comment: saw it now myself also and now it works how it should. i am programming in visual studio and there i tried the debugger but i didnt work that way that it showed me the current value of the variable